# Unresolved enumerator name in Rust

Tags: rust

Following the Rust guide, I wanted to run the example from section 8 and 9.

```
enum MOrdering {
    MLess,
    MEqual,
    MGreater,
}

fn cmp(a: int, b: int) -> MOrdering {
    if a < b { MLess }
    else if a > b { MGreater }
    else { MEqual }
}

fn main() {
    let x = 5i;
    let y = 3i;

    match cmp(x, y) {
        MLess => println!("less"),
        MGreater => println!("greater"),
        MEqual => println!("equal"),
    }

}
```

This does not compile and it appears to be the same as the example with just the enum renamed to make sure it didn't conflict with core::cmp::Ordering.

These are the errors I get while compiling:

```
rustc src/main.rs
src/main.rs:8:16: 8:21 error: unresolved name `MLess`. Did you mean `a`?
src/main.rs:8     if a < b { MLess }
                             ^~~~~
src/main.rs:9:21: 9:29 error: unresolved name `MGreater`.
src/main.rs:9     else if a > b { MGreater }
                                  ^~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:10:12: 10:18 error: unresolved name `MEqual`. Did you mean `a`?
src/main.rs:10     else { MEqual }
                          ^~~~~~
error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
```

What am I missing that the guide left out? On Rust 0.13.
`rustc 0.13.0-nightly (fac5a0767 2014-11-26 22:37:06 +0000)`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It works in Rust 0.12! Maybe it’s a bug; I can’t see anything obvious in https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/compare/0.12.0...master.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug; a little time ago [an RFC on enum variants scoping](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/390) has been implemented. Now enum variants are scoped under their respective enums, so you need to write this:

```
enum MOrdering {
    MLess,
    MEqual,
    MGreater,
}

fn cmp(a: int, b: int) -> MOrdering {
    if a < b { MOrdering::MLess }
    else if a > b { MOrdering::MGreater }
    else { MOrdering::MEqual }
}

fn main() {
    let x = 5i;
    let y = 3i;

    match cmp(x, y) {
        MOrdering::MLess => println!("less"),
        MOrdering::MGreater => println!("greater"),
        MOrdering::MEqual => println!("equal"),
    }
}
```

You can revert to the old behavior by using glob imports:

```
#![feature(globs)]

use MOrdering::*;

enum MOrdering {
    MLess,
    MEqual,
    MGreater,
}

fn cmp(a: int, b: int) -> MOrdering {
    if a < b { MLess }
    else if a > b { MGreater }
    else { MEqual }
}

fn main() {
    let x = 5i;
    let y = 3i;

    match cmp(x, y) {
        MLess => println!("less"),
        MGreater => println!("greater"),
        MEqual => println!("equal"),
    }
}
```

(note: soon enabling feature flag for globs will be unnecessary because globs are planned for stabilization for 1.0)

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the [prelude](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/) also exports the variants for the enums it exports, which is why variants such as `Some` and `Greater` don't need to be qualified.

Comment: I opened a pull request today to add this information to the Guide too https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/19616